# How to pass React component as a child and add props inside this conponent

Tags: reactjs, react-props

I have an object

```
const obj = {
 name: 'Milk', component <Milk />;
 name: 'Bread', component <Bread />;
 name: 'Tea', component <Tea />;
}
```

I send this object as prop to the child component. In this child component I should send chosen component and add quantity as props

```
const view = obj.map((item) => item.name === product.name)
return (
 {view.component}
)
```

As a result a send only `<Milk />`, but I need `<Milk quantity={quantity} />`
Can I somehow add props to the object. I can't do it in the parent component.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could re-structure your object like this:

```
const obj = {
  Milk: <Milk />,
  Bread: <Bread />,
  Tea: <Tea />,
};
```

And then, after retrieving it, you could add props using the `cloneElement` method:

```
const view = obj[product.name]
if (view) {
    const viewWithProps = React.cloneElement(view, { quantity: <custom-quantity> })
    return (
        {viewWithProps}
    )
}
```